# Why is the string *RECURSION* appearing in the output and every contained array name is initiating with underscore character in $GLOBALS array output?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, global-variables

I'm using following PHP version on my local machine and running the PHP programs from localhost only.

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.13 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul  7 2014 18:54:55)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

I've written a very simple PHP program as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

  <?php
    $x = 5;
    $y = 10;

    print_r($GLOBALS);
    die;

    function myTest() {
      global $x, $y;
      $y = $x + $y;
    }


    myTest(); // Run function

    echo $y; // Output the new value for variable $y
  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

After executing the above program I'm getting following output in a browser window:

```
Array ( [GLOBALS] => Array *RECURSION* [_POST] => Array ( ) [_GET] => Array ( ) [_COOKIE] => Array ( ) [_FILES] => Array ( ) [x] => 5 [y] => 10 )
```

From the above output I'm not getting why the string *RECURSION* is getting displayed, from where it came. What's the cause behind it?

Also, why is the underscore character appearing at the beginning of all contained arrays**(_POST, _GET, _FILES)**?

Comment: As for your other question, it's a convention of a sort. Several so-called 'super-global' variables (that store either the environment details or the details of a specific request) have names beginning with underscore.

Comment: @raina77ow:If you could give me the descriptive, canonical and precise answer it would be of great help to beginners and newbies to PHP like me. Can you please do this as a favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to think of it is by imagining how it would have been if `*RECURSIVE*` WOULDN'T have been displayed:

```
Array 
( 
    [GLOBALS] => Array 
        (
            [GLOBALS] = Array
                (
                      [GLOBALS] = Array
                          (
                                  ...
                          )
                      ...
                )
            [_POST] => Array ( )
            [_GET] => Array ( )
            ...
        ) 
    [_POST] => Array ( ) 
    [_GET] => Array ( ) 
    [_COOKIE] => Array ( ) 
    [_FILES] => Array ( ) 
    [x] => 5 
    [y] => 10 
)
```

`$GLOBALS` contains references to all global variables, and since `$GLOBAL` is a global variable itself, it also contains a reference to itself. As you can see, the above will result in a recursive pattern, which never ends, simply because the `$GLOBALS`-array contains a reference to itself as an element. This means that printing it with `print_r()` would be impossible, since it would result in infinite recursion. Therefore, the `print_r()` function solves this by adding the string `*RECURSION*` instead. Here's a quote from the [PHP-manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

> Prior to PHP 4.0.4, print_r() will continue forever if given an array or object that contains a direct or indirect reference to itself. An example is print_r($GLOBALS) because $GLOBALS is itself a global variable that contains a reference to itself.

This also means that displaying any object which contains recursive references to themselves will lead to this string being displayed. A simple example is:

```
$a = array(&$a); //$a contains one element with a reference to itself
print_r($a); //prints: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array *RECURSION* ) )
```

Although note that this won't hide any info from you - you still know what the `GLOBALS`-element contains (the same thing as printed, basically), if having all this in mind.

To answer your second question: The reason the names start with and underscore is simply because several "super-global" variables do so. It makes it easier to distinguish the super-globals from regular variables, and (somewhat) prevents people from using those names by mistake. So when accessing the `_POST`-array for instance, you use `$_POST` instead of just `$POST`, meaning that the element-key in the `$GLOBALS`-variable becomes `_POST`, as it's the "actual" name of the variable.